# Numpy related Error while running a docker container

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, numpy, python-venv

I composed a docker image file that gets built successfully.

However, when I run a container with that image, it produces the following numpy error and exits.

Any idea how this could be corrected?

### ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/./MetReTrim", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/opt/venv/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install numpy outside of docker, and copied the venv?

If so, C extensions were compiled for your host (which, according to the error, is not Linux)

You'll need to install numpy into the container itself